# Implicitly global "item" variable - difference between Internet Explorer and FireFox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scope, global-variables

Just out of curiosity..

I have this JS code:

```
var someExternalArray = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}];
var newArray = []

//var item;
for (var i = 0; i < someExternalArray.length; i++){
    item = new Object();
    item.id = someExternalArray[i].id;
    item.name = someExternalArray[i].name;
    newArray.push(item);
}

alert('0:' + newArray[0].name + ',1:' + newArray[1].name + ',2:' + newArray[2].name);
```

Notice the commented `var item` which leaves the loop with implicitly declared `item` variable.

- If I run this code on FireFox, the result of alert is: `0:a,1:b,2:c`
- If I run the same code in Internet Explorer, the result is:
  `0:c,1:c,2:c`

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvu9gb26/

Of course, when I uncomment the `var item` it works the same way in every browser.

Does anyone know why this difference occurs? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, that's because Internet Explorer's `window` object exposes an [item()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536460.aspx) method that your script cannot overwrite.

In the line:

```
item = new Object();
```

`item` is not declared in the local scope, so it is interpreted as a property of the global object (`window.item`). On Firefox, `window` does not expose a member named `item`, so a new member is introduced and the result of `new Object()` is assigned to it.

On the other hand, Internet Explorer exposes a native method named `window.item()`. That member is not writeable, so the assignment cannot take place -- it is silently ignored. In other words, `item = new Object()` has no effect at all (well, it does create an object but cannot assign it afterwards).

The subsequent assignments to `id` and `name` end up creating new members of the `item()` method. These are always the same members of the same method, so their values are overwritten on every loop iteration. In addition, the same object (the `item()` method) is pushed to the array on every iteration.

Therefore, the array ends up containing three times the same object, and the values of its `id` and `name` members are the last values assigned to them (in the last iteration), respectively `3` and `'c'`.

Comment: Thank you. This really was a coincident that we forgot to declare `var item` as we always do declare variable in our project and never rely on implicit declarations. And second, that this variable has the same name as some native method on `window object` which exists only in IE..wow :)

Answer (score 5):

This is tricky. For some obscure reason, Internet Explorer has a native method called `item` in the global context `window` (if someone knows why, you're welcome to share: I can't find it in the documentation). So, when you use the identifier `item` without declaring a variable, it refers to this method.

The first instruction in the loop (`item = new Object();`) does nothing because `window.item` is a readonly property. So, after this instruction, `window.item` is still the native function.

The next instructions (those which sets `id` and `name`) works, because while the property `window.item` is readonly, the `Function` object it's pointing to can be modified.

After the loops, you added the same `Function` object three times, and only the last iteration counts because you override the `id` and `name` properties everytime.

Comment: LMAO!! I stumbled upon here because I was using the item context as well in my for loop. I was looping through items from my inventory from JSON and assigned the variable item to it... weird stuff microsoft! Haha. Simple fix for me was just to add var before item.